# Upgrade from windows 7 to 8.1 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, windows-7, windows-8

I have a dual-boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 16.04 , Now I need to upgrade windows 7 to 8.1 to be specific I want a "Clean Install which format the win 7 partition then install the win 8.1" so how to do that ? I think this won't effect Ubuntu partition but it will effect the (GRUB) so how to install grub from windows ?

I usually when get a GRUB rescue I use some GRUB commands then when boot from Ubuntu use this commands :

`sudo grub-update` then `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: You're in luck as I successfully did this recently. After Win 8.1 install I downloaded Grub for Windows. Setup an option to call Ubuntu. Then reboot I get Windows multi-boot with Grub for Windows and select Ubuntu. From there run `sudo update-grub` which creates a new boot menu with Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 7. Then on subsequent boots Grub multi OS loader greets you instead of Windows multi-OS loader.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thank you I will try it now

Comment: Look at the answers below before trying it. I never had a live USB / DVD... that's a work in progress with UEFI and CSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert your Ubuntu LiveDVD / USB .
2. after boot use `try Ubuntu`
3. when live system started
4. open terminal by using `CTRL + ALT + T`
5. then type `sudo grub-update`
6. then type `sudo grub-install`

That's it !

## Update 1

mostly you will get error when using `sudo grub-install` on live environment so do steps bellow (on live env too):

P.S: make sure you have completely shutdown your Windows before do this
to do this from windows CMD or RUN type `shutdown /r /t 0` .

1. Open Terminal   (CTRL + ALT + T).
2. mount the Ubuntu partition by `sudo mount /dev/sd# /mnt` replace # with your Ubuntu partition as ex. `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
3. mount the boot partition `sudo mount /dev/sd# /mnt/boot` replace # with boot partition, in most cases the boot partition is "sda1"
4. finally use `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX` replace X with the order of disk you want to install grub on it , if you use a single hard drive  it will be `sda`

It's done for now see `Update 2`

## Update 2 (can also used for grub rescue)

after you installed grub successfully from `Update 1` and restart , you will get a grub command line screen do the following commands :

1. type `ls` you will get the partitions in order similar to this :
   (hd0)(hd0,msdos4)(hd0,msdos3)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)
2. type `ls (hd0,X)` replace X with the number ,
   you will get unknown file system , do it until you get `file system ext2` that's our target
3. after we get our target partition type `set root=(hd0,X)` replace X with target partition number
4. then `set prefix=(hd0,X)/boot/grub`
5. (For x32 bit, works both for i386 and i686 systems) type `insmod /boot/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod`
6. (for x64 bit systems do step 5 too if you get Not found do this ) type `/boot/grub/linux.mod`
7. (if step 6 not working only) type `ls /boot/grub` to see the directories and files  check every folder to find the `linux.mod` file , then do the step 6 with modified path.
8. type `normal` you will find your normal grub boot-loader boot into Ubuntu
9. from Ubuntu terminal type `sudo update-grub`
10. then `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` replace X with the device , mostly it's `sda`

All done ! .

Comment: Most of it is not applicable to UEFI/GPT systems.  You could improve your answer by rewriting it instead of adding corrections as "updates".